# Directory Listing Script - Small fix - INDEX.PHP "self"

Tags: php, listview, directory

There is a scrip which I have found MOST useful. It can be found below:

[Directory Listing Script - Version 3](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script)

IT has a variaty of features and I use to it view all my website that I am working on. However this is a problem which I cannot find a solution as yet. I have tried the developers website however the last response on the comments was on the `July 06, 2012 at 1:50 am`.

Here is the feature which is great.

```
    /*
Index files - The follow array contains all the index files
that will be used if $displayindex (above) is set to true.
Feel free to add, delete or alter these
*/

$indexfiles = array (
                'index.html',
                'index.htm',
                'index.php',
                'default.htm',
                'default.html'
            );
```

SO when if finds the file above it executes it.

The name of the script is index.php however when I have 'index.php' listed above it does not work. If I rename the script to 'start.php' then it works however I have to click on it as it is looking for index.php.

As the script is quite long, I would recommend downloading it and having a look to save a bit from clutter.

My Question: what would I need to edit so the index.php loads. At present it does not if present in the above code.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to execute or load  index.php from index.php??? i didnt get your logic

Comment: @Surace I am try to load the index.php... However if I include it in the above code. it does not load the index.php at root. Just come up with "this page cannot be found".

Comment: I have the part of the code in the script which is `if($displayindex) {
    if(in_array(strtolower($file), $indexfiles)) {
     header("Location: $leadon$file");
     die();'if($displayindex) {
    if(in_array(strtolower($file), $indexfiles)) {
     header("Location: $leadon$file");
     die();`

Comment: If the script is named index.php it self. it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed part of the PHP ini. All working.